# Responsive equal widths

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, percentage, fluid-layout

I'm converting a 960grid 12col responsive design to HTML. It has a three separate div each with 300px wide and margin-right of 20px width. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
 <section class="container">
        <h1>Services</h1>
        <div class="box">
            box1
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            box2
        </div>
        <div class="box last">
            box3
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
      max-width: 960px;
      width: 98%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 1.04166666666667%;/*10px / 960px*/
 }
.box{
     width: 31.25%;/*300px / 960px*/
     margin-right: 6.66666666666667%;/*20px / 300px*/
     float: left;
     background: red;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
.last{
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

And my problem is the div with class name box is not fitting inside the container div. The last div breaks the line and comes below the other two div. [Refer this.](http://oi47.tinypic.com/fa6eev.jpg) Don't know where I'm getting wrong.

Comment: Should .branding not be .box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's your margin-right which is the problem.

It should be 20 divided by 960 which is 0.020833333333333333333333333333333 which in turns becomes 2.0833333333333333333333333333333%

In responsive design the margin is calculated from the parent container not the child element.

Comment: Yeah you correct Billy. I have calculated the context as box which should be container width. Thanks problem solved.
What should do is - 20px/960px.
What I have done is - 20px/300px.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 boxes of width 31.25% width, and an additional 6.67% margin on each, except the last one.
This equals to a total of 107.09% width and can therefore not fit in it's containers width.

Lower the numbers so that they result in a total of less than 100%.

Also you should calculate margin-right by doing 20/960.

Comment: Yeah but I have add a class named last which will make the last div margin to 0.

Comment: Yes, but it is still too wide. (Edited the answer so you can see.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jimmy. I have found the Answer that is mentioned by Billy. Its actually my mistake which I should target the parent div width for the margins. But I have done is calculated with same div that has margin. Anyway thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Glad you found the issue!